# How to convert a JSON file into a different format

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, json

I am having a file having 100 lines  in below format.

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id":"01","score":"10000","Name": "ABC", "description": "<html xmlns:fo=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/XSL\/Format\" xmlns:msxsl=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt\">\n\n<head>\n\n<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text\/html\">\n\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text\/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n\n<\/head>\n\n<body style=\"margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;\">\n\n<table style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px\">\n\n<tr style=\"text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2\">\n\n<td>PASIR PANJANG 1<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>\n\n<table style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px\">\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>SHAPE<\/td>\n\n<td>Polygon<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>Subzone Number<\/td>\n\n<td>13<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>Subzone Name<\/td>\n\n<td>ABC 1<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>Subzone Code<\/td>\n\n<td>QTSZ13<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>Central Area Indicator<\/td>\n\n<td>N<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>Planning Area Name<\/td>\n\n<td>QUEENSTOWN<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>Planning Area Code<\/td>\n\n<td>QT<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>Region Name<\/td>\n\n<td>CENTRAL REGION<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>Region Code<\/td>\n\n<td>CR<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>INC_CRC<\/td>\n\n<td>1F721290C421BFAB<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>FMEL_UPD_D<\/td>\n\n<td>12\/5\/2014 9:26:20 PM<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>X_ADDR<\/td>\n\n<td>22077.3383<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>Y_ADDR<\/td>\n\n<td>29893.7812<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>SHAPE_Length<\/td>\n\n<td>6571.323082<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>SHAPE_Area<\/td>\n\n<td>1084792.320587<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<\/table>\n\n<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<\/table>\n\n<\/body>\n\n<\/html>\n\n"}, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 103.770389070495796, 1.292487855396017 ], [ 103.770414424305599, 1.292574882101212 ], [ 103.7701466034909, 1.29263278185594 ], [ 103.770073030489101, 1.292648696824341 ], [ 103.769991818022206, 1.292739600582147 ] ] ] ] } },
```

...
..
..
From this I need to convert each line to

```
01,ABC,"POLYGON((103.770389070495796, 1.292487855396017 ,  103.770414424305599, 1.292574882101212 ,  103.7701466034909, 1.29263278185594 ,  103.770073030489101, 1.292648696824341 ,  103.769991818022206, 1.292739600582147))"
```

and so on.

Can it be done in awk or sed?

Comment: First of all this is not CSV but JSON.  Secondly, blindly relying on relative positioning in data you don't know is most unreliable.  And finally, this is not a free script writing service and (as per the terms) you are required to show a minimum effort of solving the question on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -j '.properties.id, ",",
    .properties.Name, ",\"POLYGON((",
    (.geometry.coordinates | flatten | map(tostring) | join(",")), "))\"\n"' < file.json
```

Output:

```
01,ABC,"POLYGON((103.770389070496,1.29248785539602,103.770414424306,1.29257488210121,103.770146603491,1.29263278185594,103.770073030489,1.29264869682434,103.769991818022,1.29273960058215))"
```

**Edit:** [fiddle 1](https://jqplay.org/s/03Tnyc2NOy), [fiddle 2](https://jqplay.org/s/V8yu64SiQq)

Comment: I tried your way but it throws an compiler error.  Could you please check this [snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/Ct851wvqjR)

Comment: Are u able to share any fiddle or pen so it will be helpful to identify my error?

Comment: @John Edited, this should now work with `jq` 1.5.

Answer (score 4):

To process JSON, use a JSON tool, e.g. [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (normally available is a package in your distro):

```
jq -j '.properties.id, ",", .([ .geometry.coordinates | recurse | numbers | tostring] | join(",")), "))\n"' < your_file
```

does what you want for a single line. You may need to feed it each line separately, depending on how your file actually looks like.